# How do i make a js code that redirects to a certain html page with a certain input?

Tags: javascript, html

let me explain this better, i would like to know how it's possible to create a js code that checks if an html input is correct and in case it is it redirects you to another page, here is what i tried based on what i managed to find out.

html part:

```
<form name="access" onsubmit="return validate()">
  <input
    type="text"
    id="inputbox"
    value="Password"
    pattern="idkwhatishoouldwriteinhere"
  />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

js part:

```
function validate() {
  if (document.access.Password.value != "idkwhatishoouldwriteinhere") {
    alert("Wrong password");
    document.access.Password.focus();
    return false;
  } else {
    window.open("index.html");
  }
}
```

in case you are wondering why i put the "answer" in the patter is because this is supposed to be a little easter egg and i feel like looking directly at the js is meaningless becuase it contains the link you should be redirected to.
enter code here

Comment: maybe document.location?

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your input the name `Password`, otherwise `document.access.Password` is undefined.

```js
function validate() {
  if (document.access.Password.value != "idkwhatishoouldwriteinhere") {
    alert("Wrong password");
    document.access.Password.focus();
    return false;
  } else {
    window.open("index.html")
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="access" onsubmit="return validate()">
  <input type="text" id="inputbox" value="Password" name="Password" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<!-- password is "idkwhatishoouldwriteinhere" -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You want this.

You had some issues with the id of the field and name etc

I also changed your inline code to eventListener which is the recommended method

Password is `fred`

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("access").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    const inputbox = document.getElementById("inputbox");
    if (inputbox.value != "fred") {
      alert("Wrong password");
      inputbox.focus();
      e.preventDefault(); // cancel submit
    } else location.replace("index.html")

  });
})
```

```html
<form id="access">
  <input type="password" id="inputbox" value="" placeholder="Password" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: i know i'm replying a bit too late but i kinda let everything go because i couldn't figure out why i wasn't being redirected, i got back at work and i can only use window.open, do you know why and if it's possible to make the redirect work?

Comment: @u0lf Do you get console errors using location.replace? You can change `location.replace("index.html")` to `window.open("index.html")` if you want

Comment: no, i see no errors, i would just like to redirect purely because some people find opening a new annoying/use a popup blocker

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your code close to what you already have, I would adjust it like this. I would suggest storing your class names and ids as variables and then accessing them from the variable. Also there is no need to return false in your if. There are other good solutions on here but this one will keep your code pretty close. This will also ensure that you don't end up with a null value when accessing the value in your password field.

```js
const passwordField = document.getElementById('inputbox');

function validate() {
    if(passwordField.value != "idkwhatishoouldwriteinhere") {
        alert( "Wrong password" );
        passwordField.focus() ;

    }
    else {
        window.open("index.html")
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="access" onsubmit="validate()" href="javascript:void(0)">
  <input type="text" id="inputbox" value="Password" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: thank you! do i have to replace javascript:void(0) with anything? also does the destination page have to be in the same directory as the script? (because atm the scripts are in a subfolder)

Comment: @u0lf no you do not need to replace javascript:void(0) with anything, all it does is prevent default link behavior that may go against what you're trying to achieve with your script. The destination page, if it is in a sub folder, will need to be accounted for. So instead of "index.html" you would use "../index.html" the ../ tells the code to back up one directory, so you will need to add a ../ based on however many directories up your index.html page is. So if your index.html page is only one directory up, then just a single ../ will work.